# How to add tag helpers from plugins?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to add tag helpers from plugins.
Something like this in _ViewImports.cshtml:

```
@addTagHelper *, *.MyApp.*
```

That is, take all assemblies, whose name matches pattern *.MyApp.*, and add type helpers from these assemblies.

I know, that `@addTagHelper` can't do this out-of-box. But is there any extension point here?

I've found [this](http://darrelltunnell.net/blog/2016/07/25/aspnet-core-taghelper-s-a-better-addtaghelper-type-resolver/) post about `ITagHelperTypeResolver`, but it looks like this API does not exists in ASP NET Core 2+.

There are two reasons for why I just can't use standard syntax:

- this is plugin-based application (tag helpers can be defined inside plugins);
- assembly names are built dynamically. All of my project import some shared MSBuild settings, and for project named "MyApp.Foo" assembly name will be "MyCompany.MyApp.Foo".

Comment: You don't have to put `@addTagHelper *, *.MyApp.*` inside the `_ViewImports.cshtml`, that's not a law or requirement. Its just convenience, because `_ViewImports.cshtml` is automatically included in every View. You can just add `@addTagHelper *, My.Plugin.Something` into the view which actually use it. So if the view is defined in your plugin, declare it there. Same way as you declare namespaces in ever cs file ;) That being said, feel free to add a `_MyPluginImports.cshtml` and include that in every of your views, then you just have one place to change/add these tag helpers :P

Comment: `_ViewImports.cshtml` is just a regular razor file, like every view. Nothing Special

Comment: @Tseng: there are two problems. Fist, tag helpers and pages are not in the same assemblies, and pages assemblies can't refer tag helpers assemblies statically - tag helpers are plugins too. Second, I don't know assembly name statically - MSBuild build it during compilation.

Comment: @Dennis: Just trying to understand your use case: Then how do you suppose to use tags in a page, when you don't reference it? I mean, when your pages are inside an assembly (reads: are pre-compiled) then you already need to know the reference to the tag helper you want to use and can just add it (either way manually or via code generators). Or not? I mean, users of your applications won't be able to add new tags to your razor pages anyways after its been shipped. So only use case would be uncompiled pages/views, but then the user can add the reference by himself if he adds a new tag to source?

Comment: There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1917) with some hints towards a 2.0+ solution that might help.

Comment: @Tseng: actually, there are two issues here. First, I thought one could use tag helpers as a view customization tool. Your point about pre-compiled views makes sense. Probably, tag helpers can't help me here. OK. But there's the second one: I don't know full assembly name at design-time. Hence, even if I can add reference to some my project with tag helpers, `@addTagHelper` can't use project name - it requires full assembly name.

Comment: @KirkLarkin: thanks, I'll read it.